# specializing template class for pointers

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have a template class as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class PacketMember
{
public:
    PacketMember(const std::size_t maxMemberSize, const QString memberName) :
        m_maxMemberSize(maxMemberSize),
        m_memberName(memberName)
    {

    }

    void append(const T data, const std::size_t length)
    {
        if(currentMemberSize() + length <= m_maxMemberSize)
        {
            for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i) {
                m_data = data;
                m_member.push_back(m_data);
            }
        }
    }

    QString memberName() const
    {
        return m_memberName;
    }

    std::size_t currentMemberSize() const
    {
        return m_member.size();
    }

    std::size_t maxMemberSize() const
    {
        return m_maxMemberSize;
    }

    std::vector<T>* member() const
    {
        return m_member;
    }

    void setMaxMemberSize(const std::size_t newSize) {
        m_maxMemberSize = newSize;
    }

private:
    T m_data;
    std::vector<T> m_member;
    std::size_t m_maxMemberSize;
    QString m_memberName;
};
```

and a specialization for pointers as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class PacketMember<T*>
{
public:
    PacketMember(const std::size_t maxMemberSize, const QString memberName) :
        m_maxMemberSize(maxMemberSize),
        m_memberName(memberName)
    {

    }

    void append(T* data, const std::size_t length)
    {
        if(currentMemberSize() + length <= m_maxMemberSize)
        {
            for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i) {
                m_data = new T(*data);
                m_member.push_back(m_data);
            }
        }
    }

    QString memberName() const
    {
        return m_memberName;
    }

    std::size_t currentMemberSize() const
    {
        return m_member.size();
    }

    std::size_t maxMemberSize() const
    {
        return m_maxMemberSize;
    }

    std::vector<T*>* member() const
    {
        return &m_member;
    }

private:
    T* m_data;
    std::vector<T*> m_member;
    std::size_t m_maxMemberSize;
    QString m_memberName;
};
```

when i try to instantiate my class to `char*` with `PacketMember<char*>` it creates a class of `PacketMember<cha**>`. why is this happening? how should i avoid pointer-to-pointer instantiation? Sorry if it's a basic question. I've very limited experience with templates.

**EDIT:**

There was nothing wrong with my code. The problem was merely a bug in QtCreator. Should i delete this question? please reply in comments. thank you.

Comment: can you post your implementation?

Comment: @Samer implementation of what? if you mean the class member functions then it's a template everything is in the header file.

Comment: how do you instantiate your class object?

Comment: if you look at the bottom of my description I've already mentioned it but again i do it this way `PacketMember<char*> p(1, "header");` for example.

Comment: How do you know you get `PacketMember<char**>`? Please post the original error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think you get a `PacketMember<char**>`? One mistake I see is that your `member()` function returns a pointer to the member, yet you return the member itself. For your original question, this proves that there is no "double pointer" instantiation:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T*> {
    typedef T* pointertype;
};


static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>::type,int>::value,"Non-pointer: Not the same type");
static_assert(std::is_same<A<int*>::pointertype,int*>::value,"Pointer: Not the same type");

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

(I named the two typedefs differently so you can see the correct specialization is used.)

Result: It compiles.

EDIT: Since you don't use C++11, here's an adhoc trick (there might be better ways) to make it work on compilers without `static_assert`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T*> {
    typedef T* pointertype;
};


int main()
{
    A<int>::type x = (int)0;
    A<int*>::pointertype y = (int*)0;
    x++;
    y++;
    return 0;
}
```

The assignments wouldn't work if they didn't have the same type (try adding/taking away `*` from the casts). The `x++; y++;` is just to silence the compiler warning about unused variables.

Comment: I'm not using a C++11 compatible compiler. could you please edit the answer so it could be compiled with older compilers?

Comment: @MoKi `#include <cassert> ... assert(typeid((A<int>::type)) == typeid(int)); assert((typeid(A<int*>::type)) == typeid(int*))`.

Comment: oh, I'm so sorry I thought I have a problem because my IDE (QtCreator) was showing me that way not the compiler. when I was typing the function name it was showing me like I'm trying to access an instance of my template with `char**` type and due to the code being incomplete and non-compilable and my lack of experience with template I thought I'm doing something wrong. Now I've tested my code and it's not instantiating with `char**` type. This is probably a bug in QtCreator. should I delete this question?

Comment: @MoKi Good to know even your older compiler isn't broken in that fundamental way ;-).

Comment: @Oguk Sorry! I guess now I have a bug to report to Qt community.

Comment: @Oguk I'm accepting your answer because I've learned a new thing from it and that's `std::is_same` I'm definitely going to look into it and most probably I'll change my compiler to something that supports C++11.